# nasm floating point error

Tags: floating-point, x86-64, nasm, x87

Working on doing manipulations on the floating point stack:

```
fld     qword [perResult]       ;load st0 with perimeter
fsub    qword [firstSide]       ;take st0 and minus firstSide, st0= perimeter - firstSide
fmul    qword [perResult]       ;take st0 and multiply by perimeter, st0 = difference of first equation * perimeter
fstp    qword [res1]            ;take the result off of st0 and place them into variable equation1

;setting up to take perimeter minus second side
fld     qword [perResult]       ;load up perimeter into st0
fsub    qword [secondSide]      ;take st0 and minus secondSide, st0 = perimeter - secondSide
fstp    qword [eq2]
```

For some reason, if I comment out the equation to get `eq2`, i will get the right output in the previous equation to get `res1`,

but if I leave equation 2 uncommented I will get a `0` as output

and the same thing for the next equation, for some reason it's zeroing it out if there is a function after the previous.

anybody ever faced this problem before?

here is printing function

```
mov rdi, areaMsg    
call    print_string
xor r14,r14
movsd   xmm0,  [eq2]    ;move sumResult into xmm0 for printing
mov qword rax, 1
mov r14, [eq2]  ;move result into r14 register for printing float
call    print_float
call    print_nl
jmp Decision
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with the above code. I compiled and ran this under Windows XP:

```
bits 16
org 0x100

fld     qword [perResult]       ;load st0 with perimeter
fsub    qword [firstSide]       ;take st0 and minus firstSide, st0= perimeter - firstSide
fmul    qword [perResult]       ;take st0 and multiply by perimeter, st0 = difference of first equation * perimeter
fstp    qword [res1]            ;take the result off of st0 and place them into variable equation1

;setting up to take perimeter minus second side
fld     qword [perResult]       ;load up perimeter into st0
fsub    qword [secondSide]      ;take st0 and minus secondSide, st0 = perimeter - secondSide
fstp    qword [eq2]

ret

align 8

perResult       dq 11.0
firstSide       dq 1.0
res1            dq 0.0 ; (perResult - firstSide) * perResult = (11-1)*11 = 110
secondSide      dq 2.0
eq2             dq 0.0 ; perResult - secondSide = 11-2 = 9
```

And it properly calculated 110 and 9 (checked in the debugger).

If there's a problem, it's in the code that you haven't shown.